# For a WinJS app, should I use getElementById or reference the element directly?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

To reference this DOM element:

```
<input id="chkBxCheezDoodles" type="checkbox" />
```

in a Windows 8 JS app, I can do this:

```
document.getElementById("chkBxCheezDoodles").checked = true;
```

or this:

```
chkBxCheezDoodles.checked = true;
```

When (if at all) is getElementById preferred ahead of the direct reference? Is it considered "cleaner" to use getElementById?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preference is to use getElementById, rather than relying on the variable to be projected into the global namespace. This leads to no issues with similar named variables, clashes etc.

IMHO, I try not to use ID at all, and use querySelectors instead, either with a custom attribute or specific CSS classes.

Comment: I second this, here is a fiddle of what Dominic is talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/H2rJh/

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Dominic. I suspect it may be more performant if you use getElementById instead of querySelector, but I usually don't care about those nickel and dime time savings. You don't want to be typing document.querySelector all the time and I don't like having to decide between document.querySelector and querySelectorAll each time. "Let's see am I expecting one thing back or a few things back?" So I wrapped them both in a function I call query in my [ocho.js](http://codeshow.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/16267#429359) library. I usually bring it into my app into the global namespace as simply "q". That way I can always do `q("#charlie")` to get the element called "charlie" or `q(".large")` to get all of the elements with the class of large. If there's just one it returns the DOM element. If there are multiple then it returns a vanilla array. This makes my life easier. Then I can do...

```
q(".large").forEach(function(el) { el.style.fontSize = 'xx-large'; });
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely take a look at the ocho.js library. Hoping to see it as a Nuget package some time in the future.